# Responsive image mapping does not work to scaled images

Tags: html, responsive-images

I use picturefill.js for responsive image feature. When I place original image without specifying height and width, image is shown in `<picture>` tag and pull up different size of same images according to screen size.

But when i specify height and width, responsive feature does not work. Image is loaded with `<img>` tag.

[here is link](http://exrx.net/concrete/skybluesofa)

Comment: Please don't link to the problem... "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers".  Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the library explains you should manage the image size by using the sizes tag:

```
<img
  sizes="(min-width: 40em) 80vw, 100vw"
  srcset="examples/images/medium.jpg 375w,
          examples/images/large.jpg 480w,
          examples/images/extralarge.jpg 768w"
  alt="…">
```

By defining a style with a width and height you are forcing the image to keep that aspect.

From the site:

*The sizes syntax is used to define the spaces your image will occupy in your layout. srcset then defines a list of images and their inherent widths. This allows the browser to choose the smallest appropriate source for the size available in that part of the layout, rather than the viewport size alone.*